# Parsing error: Invalid value for lib provided: es2022.string | typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint, es2022

I am getting below error in all my .ts/.tsx files after running "npm run lint". I am very new to react and fixing lint error for the first time.

I found few solutions on stackoverflow for es2021. But didn't found anything for es2022.

[image]

npm version - 6.12.1
Node version - 12.13.1
typescript version - 4.3.5

Comment: `es2022.string` doesn't seem to be a component listed in [individual library components](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#individual-library-components). If you want `replaceAll` that's `es2021` or later.

Comment: Thanks @kellys for responding but I am not sure how to fix it. Do I need to do any changes in my config or package.json file?